# I cant go to specific page from chosing gridview dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview, one coloumn in the gridview is a dropdownlist, and the dropdownlist will determine the page that will be load after click the select button.
I end with an error "Object Reference not set to an instance of an object".
Here is my code (aspx.cs page)

```
protected void gv_dalamkota_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = gv_dalamkota.SelectedRow;           

    DropDownList ddl_jenis_kuitansi = sender as DropDownList;

    if (ddl_jenis_kuitansi.SelectedValue == "1")
    {
        Response.Redirect("dalamkota_rincian_dua.aspx");
    }
    else if (ddl_jenis_kuitansi.SelectedValue == "2")
    {
        Response.Redirect("dalamkota_rincian_satu.aspx");
    }
}
```

and here is my dropdown

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gv_dalamkota"
    CssClass="table table-bordered"
    runat="server"
    BorderColor="#1E6BBC"
    BorderStyle="None"
    BorderWidth="1px"
    CellPadding="3"
    ShowFooter="True"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    AllowPaging="True"
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="gv_dalamkota_SelectedIndexChanged"
    OnPageIndexChanging="OnPaging" DataSourceID="ds_dalamkota">
    <RowStyle BackColor="#EFEFEF" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="white" />
    <PagerStyle CssClass="gridview" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="nond" HeaderText="Nomor ND" SortExpression="nond" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="nost" HeaderText="Nomor Surat Tugas" SortExpression="nost" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="halst" HeaderText="Hal Surat Tugas" SortExpression="halst" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Jenis Kuitansi">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_jenis_kuitansi" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="Kuitansi 1 Tahap"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="Kuitansi 2 Tahap"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" ControlStyle-CssClass="btn btn-success">
            <ControlStyle CssClass="btn btn-success"></ControlStyle>
        </asp:CommandField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Add AutoPostBack="true" to your DropDown. Object Reference is not set. Means First You Have to Find the Controls then You can Select the DropDown Items inside gridview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are casting `sender as DropDownList` while here `sender` is not the `dropdown` and can't be casted to `DropDown` so it is `null` that's why you are getting `Null Reference Exception`.

What you need to do is `find` the `dropdown` from `grdiview` and then perform rest of your actions.

```
DropDownList ddl_jenis_kuitansi = row.FindControl("ddl_jenis_kuitansi") as DropDownList;
```

Comment: Thank for your response Mairaj Ahmad, I have delete the DropDownList ddl_jenis_kuitansi = sender as DropDownList; and change as you have suggested, but unfortunately it still doesnt work . The error come on this line  if (ddl_jenis_kuitansi.SelectedValue == "1")

Comment: Thank you for your response all, it has work: DropDownList jenis_kuitansi = row.FindControl("ddl_jenis_kuitansi") as DropDownList;
            i change, ddl_jenis_kuitansi to jenis_kuitansi only. Merci Beaucoup.

Comment: @AndreasSyaloomKurniawan please mark as answer if it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you can't get the dropdown value directly from gridview use the below line of code
for this

```
 GridViewRow row = gv_dalamkota.SelectedRow;           


        System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList ddl_jenis_kuitansi= row.FindControl("lblName") as System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList;

    if (ddl_jenis_kuitansi.SelectedValue == "1")
    {
        Response.Redirect("dalamkota_rincian_dua.aspx");
    }
    else if (ddl_jenis_kuitansi.SelectedValue == "2")
    {
        Response.Redirect("dalamkota_rincian_satu.aspx");
    }
```